# How to show that the image of the unit circle under the mapping $F(x,y)=(2x,3y)$ is an ellipse?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm studying from Serge Lang's *Introduction to Linear Algebra*, and am unsure how to proceed with a problem. Most results online for this query seem to lead down a path in complex analysis.

> In each case, to prove that the image is equal to certain set S, you must prove that the image is contained in S, and also that every element of S is in the image.
>
> 8. Let $F : R^2 \to R^2$ be the mapping defined by F(x, y) = (2x, 3y). Describe the image of the points lying on the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.

I understand I'll have a circle mapping to an ellipse, but as far as any proof is concerned, I'm failing to make use of the advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If $(a,b)$ satisfies $x^2+y^2=1$, then $(2a, 3b)$ satisfies the equation $(x/2)^2+(y/3)^2=1$. Hence each point in the image lies on the ellipse $(x/2)^2+(y/3)^2=1$.

Conversely, given a point $(c,d)$ lying on this ellipse, meaning $(c/2)^2+(d/3)^2=1$, we see that it is the image of the point $(c/2, d/3)$, which obviously lies on the unit circle.

Comment: Perhaps it is the stated solution in the back, "Ellipse 9x^2 + 4y^2 = 36", which is confusing me?

Comment: @Krpcannon: What's confusing about that? Can't you see the relationship between $(x/2)^2+(y/3)^2=1$ and $9x^2+4y^2=36$? If you can't see it, you should think about it more.

Comment: Your right, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The point $(x,y)=(\cos(t),\sin(t)($ of the circle will have $(X,Y)=(2\cos(t),3\sin(t))$ as the image.
so $\frac{X^2}{4}+\frac{Y^2}{9}=1$ which is the catesian equation of an ellipse.